sitemesh applying decorator on ajax calls returning jsp
Recently upgraded the spring boot project which were previously using opensymphony but it stopped support so had to migrate to org.sitemesh where did the configurations as documented.
I added this mapping in sitemesh3.xml in my spring boot project still the ajax call's which returns jsp is adding the default decorator because of
I want a way to not include this default.jsp decorator in ajax calls
In some of ajax calls I am returning the modelview but not expecting the default decorator to be applied.
I tried excluding individual url as well but that also didnot worked but even if that works it wont be useful becuase there are many urls.
